# Could someone explain Opengl Matrix order?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl

I'm trying to get 2 different sprites to move but i'm stuck on the question of does the matrix go out of scope past the function and can only be used in that function or is there a way to switch to a different matrix?

Comment: What matrix? What function? Hard to tell without seeing your code.

Comment: The Projection and Modelview matrix.

Comment: And by function I mean standard c++ functions. @CaptainObvlious

Comment: that which you set using glMatrixMode, glRotate, glTranslate etc functions? Why would it "go out of scope", when it's not a C/C++ construct? OpenGL functions either draw something, or change the state of OpenGL context, and i guess you use only one GL context, right?
And matrices can be pushed and poped on matrix stacks, see functions like glPushMatrix/PopMatrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL models a state machine. All changes to the matrices are permanent. Actually, OpenGL does not even know about the functions it is called from.

If you want to have a scope, you can wrap your changes in `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix`.

ex.

```
void func()
{
  glPushMatrix();
  glLoadIdentity();
  glTranslatef(1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
  // Render here
  glPopMatrix(); // Restore prior matrix state
}
```

Comment: So putting it between the Push and PopMatrix functions makes it ready to be used by another object hmm? What if I want two objects to move at the same time?

Comment: Oh! There we go! Thanks!